# How to change ListPreference button colors?

Tags: android, android-styles, listpreference, material-components-android

I use bellow style to change Dialog background color to dark, In preference page I use `ListPreference` and after apply this style, `cancel` button of ListPreference disappeared in dialog background.

```
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#212D3B</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#172331</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#61A3D7</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#212D3B</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#61A3D7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#8DB2D3</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#61A3D7</item>
</style>
```

**Is there a way to change this button color?**

[image: ListPreference]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally I found solution. I don't understand what is different between `android:alertDialogTheme` and `alertDialogTheme` (without `android:`) but preference screen used the `alertDialogTheme` to stylize dialogs. 
By adding bellow item to `AppThemeBase`, my problem is resolved.

```
<item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
```

Final `AppThemeBase` :

```
<style name="AppThemeBase" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#212D3B</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#172331</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#61A3D7</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AppTheme.Dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Dialog" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#212D3B</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">#61A3D7</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#8DB2D3</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">#61A3D7</item>
</style>
```

Comment: The problem is, this applies to every dialog in your app